# Processing Dirty Regions -> AbstractInterceptorDrivenBeanDefinitionDecorator

Tags: eclipse, spring

I use the latest Springsource ToolSuite (STS) version 2.5.0 (based on Eclipse) and on startup I get this error message:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Processing Dirty Regions".
org/springframework/aop/config/AbstractInterceptorDrivenBeanDefinitionDecorator
```

The error occurs by opening my app-config.xml

```
An internal error occurred during: "Initialize Beans Graph 'app-config.xml'".
org/springframework/aop/config/AbstractInterceptorDrivenBeanDefinitionDecorator
```

The content of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.domain.project" />

<!-- Application Message Bundle -->
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
</bean>

<!-- Configures Spring MVC -->
<import resource="mvc-config.xml" />
</beans>
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Thank you in advance & Best Regards.

Comment: Oh, of course, you are right, I will change it.

Comment: In version 2.5.1. I also have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a STS bug.  You should never see this message otherwise.